# How to find properties file inside a jar inside a war

Tags: java, spring, maven

So I was building my project whose structure is given below:

```
WEB-INF
|
|---classes
|---lib
    |
    |--- my_jar1.jar
    |--- my_jar2.jar
    |--- my_jar3.jar
    |--- interested_jar.jar
            |
            |--- com
            |     |--- company
            |           |--- folder1
            |                  |--- folder2
            |                           |--- folder3
            |                                   |--- calling_class.java
            |--- META-INF
            |--- my_properties.properties
```

This is a servlet based application. Build is maven. I want to load my_properties.properties file from calling_class.java. There are many jars inside the war. The jars are bundled up in the war file. So far I've tried

```
InputStream ioStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_properties.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(ioStream);
```

```
InputStream ioStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("my_properties.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(ioStream);
```

After the deployment, I'm getting NullPointException when loading the properties. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try ```InputStream ioStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my_properties.properties");``` (Pref in try-with-resources)

Comment: @g00se I also tried the solution you suggested it is still giving me NullPointerException. Tried the same with
```
InputStream ioStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/my_properties.properties");
```

Comment: `new ClassPathResource("/my_properties.properties").getInputStream()`. Let Spring handle the loading, or if they need to be part of the SPring properties just add an `@PropertySource("classpath:/my_properties.properties")` to your configuration class, Spring will load it and you can access the properties through the `Environment`.